# Device not listed / ADB dropping my device 2017 SDK 25

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-tools

Can connect MTP but not over ADB. ADB DEVICES shows nothing. Will go all afternoon, works fine, then suddenly cannot push to device from Android Studio. I have tried to no avail:

Re/starting ADB

Checking thaT SDK is installed

Driver issues (Can see filesystem)

Switching to a USB 2.0 from 3.0

Restarting dev machine, android phone, android studio

**Revoking debugging authorizations worked for some period of time before adb fails to see the device again**

What ELSE could be preventing this? Worked fine for so long after the last SDK 25 update and today and yesterday I lose connection frequently.

EDIT: Is my device possibly failing somehow? Has me wondering would cause revoked USB debug certs like this? Meaning to try another one when I get my hands on it later

Comment: This is of no help to you, but for the record I've recently developed possibly the same issue. This is with 2 separate Android devices. After a device reboot, and sometimes after connecting/disconnecting the USB cable, the adb connection is sometimes briefly established but drops out after a second or two. Most frustrating, and thus far I have found no clues to what's going on

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This worked for 5 hours, and now does not work. It keeps asking me allow USB debugging when I plug in because I did not check the box, however adb still fails to see the device listed.**

So far it is working after I went to USB debugging options in Android phone and pressed "Revoke USB debugging authorizations". Prompted to add authorization, accepted and seems to work.

Debugging Authorizations. How do these just, "go bad"? Expiration date?